# SQL metric rows to date columns-

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Suppose I have the following table:

```
Client  ContainerID   Year  Month   NumberOfViews
bar     116025        2019    1         2
dandy   2753          2020    1         3
dandy   2753          2020    2         2
dandy   4247          2020    1         1
demo    20037         2019    1         1
```

I want it to transform to the following table:

```
Client  ContainerID   Jan-2019  Jan-2020 Feb-2020   
bar     116025        2         0        0
dandy   2753          0         3        2
dandy   4247          0         1        0
demo    20037         1         0        0
```

meaning: year + month cell rows turns into columns and the value for 'NumberOfViews' goes to the right date column.

Comment: What is your database name?

Comment: [dbo].[LogRecordDetails]

Comment: I mean your RDBMS :) MSSQL or MySQL or Oracle...?

Comment: oh, right :)  MSSQL.

Comment: [FROM - Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

There you go.

Replace your table name:

```sql
WITH cte AS(
SELECT Client
      ,ContainerId
      ,NumberOfViews
      ,FORMAT(CAST(CAST([Year] AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST([Month] AS CHAR(2)) + '-01' AS DATE), 'MMM-yyyy') AS [DateCol] 
  FROM dbo.Test)

SELECT Client
      ,ContainerId
      ,ISNULL([Jan-2019], 0) AS [Jan-2019]
      ,ISNULL([Jan-2020], 0) AS [Jan-2020]
      ,ISNULL([Feb-2020], 0) AS [Feb-2020]
  FROM cte
 PIVOT  
(  
    SUM(NumberOfViews)  
    FOR DateCol IN ([Jan-2019], [Jan-2020], [Feb-2020])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a Dynamic PIVOT as the month-year is not static. Please try this below logic-

Please use your original table name where ever you found "your_table" in the script.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@sqlCommand  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT  @cols =
STUFF((SELECT   ( '],[' +  A.YM)
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
            CASE Month
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Jan-' WHEN 2 THEN 'Feb-' WHEN 3 THEN 'Mar-'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'Apr-' WHEN 5 THEN 'May-' WHEN 6 THEN 'Hun-'
                WHEN 7 THEN 'Jul-' WHEN 8 THEN 'Aug-' WHEN 9 THEN 'Sep-'
                WHEN 10 THEN 'Oct-' WHEN 11 THEN 'Nov-' WHEN 12 THEN 'Dec-'
            END
            + CAST(Year AS VARCHAR) YM
            FROM your_table
        ) A
        ORDER BY A.YM 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')+']'
FROM your_table

SET @sqlCommand= 
N'SELECT Client,ContainerID,'+SUBSTRING(@cols,2,LEN(@cols))+'
FROM 
(
    SELECT Client,ContainerID,YM,NumberOfViews 
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT Client,ContainerID,NumberOfViews,
        CASE Month
            WHEN 1 THEN ''Jan-'' WHEN 2 THEN ''Feb-'' WHEN 3 THEN ''Mar-''
            WHEN 4 THEN ''Apr-'' WHEN 5 THEN ''May-'' WHEN 6 THEN ''Hun-''
            WHEN 7 THEN ''Jul-'' WHEN 8 THEN ''Aug-'' WHEN 9 THEN ''Sep-''
            WHEN 10 THEN ''Oct-'' WHEN 11 THEN ''Nov-'' WHEN 12 THEN ''Dec-''
        END
        + CAST(Year AS VARCHAR) YM
        FROM your_table
    )A
) AS P
PIVOT
(
    SUM(NumberOfViews)
    FOR YM IN('+SUBSTRING(@cols,2,LEN(@cols))+')
) PVT'

--PRINT @sqlCommand
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```